# Is there any second method to calculate this limit?

Tags: calculus

In my college, we can just use the sandwich theorem to calculate two variables' limits, with the polar method I find that:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x^2 + y^2)^2}{x^2-y^2}$$
But I can't find a way to prove that using other method like sandwich theorem, or some changes

Comment: how did you find that the limit is $0$ using polar coordinates?

Comment: We consider: x=r.cos(ø) and y=r. Sin(ø) with r>0 and ø€[0,2pi[

Comment: I know polar coordinates, how did you conclude that the limit is $0$?

Comment: when it is easy for the denominator to be zero (near but not at the origin),  there will be no limit unless the numerator is forced to be zero.....

Comment: The Limit when r--> 0 and for ø different from pi/4 and k.pi/2 ((r^2)^2)/(r(cos(ø)^2-sin(ø)^2)) = Limit when r--> 0 and for ø different from pi/4 and k.pi/2 (r^2)/((cos(ø)^2-sin(ø)^2)) = 0, because 1/(cos(ø)^2-sin(ø)^2) is  a borne and r go to 0

Comment: try the path $y=x-x^3$

Comment: I find 2, but I can't reach a conclusion since the limit exist

Comment: Alia, the limit DOES NOT EXIST!

Comment: @Mittens if you write this comment in the form of an answer the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The limit in the OP does not exist. In porlar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$

$$\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{r^4}{r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}=\frac{r^2}{\cos(2\theta)}$$
If we let $(x,y)$ approach $(0,0)$ along the curve $2\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-r^2$ for example, we get
$$
\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{r^2}{\sin r^2}\xrightarrow{r\rightarrow0}1$$
while if we let $(x,y)$ approach $(0,0)$ through the line $y=ax$, $|a|\neq1$,  we obtain
$$\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{x^2(1+a^2)^2}{1-a^2}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0}0$$

Answer (score 2):

This method, of Sine of the Times, shows a useful skill. If there is to be a limit at the origin, it must be that the limit along every path reaching the origin is the same there.  One might call this a directional limit, but the important thing is that these paths are not going to have constant $\theta$= x^2 -  in polar coordinates.

Show, talk about your limit when restricting to the curve $$y = x - x^4$$

Deliberately writing  with increasing exponents, we get
$$ y^2 = x^2 - 2 x^5 + x^8  $$
$$ x^2 +y^2 = 2x^2 - 2 x^5 + x^8  $$
$$ x^2 -y^2 =  2 x^5 - x^8  $$

The numerator comes out
$$  (x^2 + y^2)^2 = 4 x^4 - 8 x^7 + 8 x^{10} - 4 x^{13}  + x^{16}  $$

or numerator:
$$  (x^2 + y^2)^2 =x^4 \left( 4  - 8 x^3 + 8 x^{6} - 4 x^{9}  + x^{12} \right)  $$

Denominator
$$  x^2 - y^2 = x^5 \left( 2 - x^3  \right)  $$

Ratio:
$$  \frac{1}{x}    \left( \frac{ 4  - 8 x^3 + 8 x^{6} - 4 x^{9}  + x^{12}}{ 2 - x^3 } \right)       $$

As $x$ goes to zero, the ratio is hardly distinguishable from
$$ \frac{4}{2x} =   \frac{2}{x}  $$
and goes to $+ \infty$ for positive $x$  and $- \infty$  for negative $x$

Indeed, the difference goes to zero, since
$$ \frac{2}{x} - \frac{1}{x}    \left( \frac{ 4  - 8 x^3 + 8 x^{6} - 4 x^{9}  + x^{12}}{ 2 - x^3 } \right)  = \frac{6x^2 - 8 x^5 + 4 x^8 - x^{11}}{2-x^3}       $$